# Edit User and password

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony4

I need help please with my app in symfony 4.

I try to edit a user but I don't need to change the password.

This is my code:

```
   $form = $this->createForm(UtilisateurType::class, $utilisateur);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $utilisateur->setPassword($passwordEncoder->encodePassword($utilisateur, $utilisateur->getPassword()));
        $this->em->merge($utilisateur);
        $this->em->flush();
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Edition Utilisateur avec succés');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin.adminadmin.list');
    }

    return $this->render(
        'admin/edit.html.twig',
        [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]
    );
```

When I try to save a user Symfony gets my password in blank.

---

My FormType is:

```
$builder
        ->add('nom', TextType::class)
        ->add('prenom', TextType::class)
        ->add(
            'role',
            ChoiceType::class,
            [
            'choices' => [
                'Administrateur' => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
                'Commercial' => 'ROLE_COM',
            ],
            ]
        )
        ->add('quota_fiche', HiddenType::class)
        ->add(
            'username',
            EmailType::class,
            [
            'label' => 'Email',
            ]
        )
        ->add(
            'password',
            RepeatedType::class,
            [
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'invalid_message' => 'Les mots de passes ne sont pas identique.',
            'options' => ['attr' => ['class' => 'password-field'], 'always_empty' => false],
            'required' => true,
            'first_options'  => ['label' => 'Mot de Passe'],
            'second_options' => ['label' => 'Confirmer Mot de Passe'],
            ]
        );
```

I use this:

```
$utilisateur->setPassword($passwordEncoder->encodePassword($utilisateur, $utilisateur->getPassword()));
```

Because i think it's a methode to get old password in db.

Comment: What does the UtilisateurType class look like?

Comment: The class UtilisateurType look like this in my coment below.
But i resolve my problm to creat a new form for edit password and edit user.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is here :

```
$utilisateur->setPassword($passwordEncoder->encodePassword($utilisateur, $utilisateur->getPassword()));
```

But, I need to see your formType before identifying real issue

Comment: Thanks Jess, i solved my problem with creat a new form edituser and edit password.